# Access Query - Only group by certain objects

Tags: ms-access

I'm having to use MS Access to query local tables. I want to group by only certain objects but Access only allows you to group by everything, or apply no grouping at all.

I'm used to MySql where I can just do something similar to below:

```
SELCT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `tblMyTable` GROUP BY `a`;
```

But if I try this in Access, it changes everything I'm not grouping by to Expressions and then  complains that they are not part of an aggregate function.

Is this intentional on behalf of Microsoft or a bug?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried changing it to 'sql mode' and manually editing the grouping

Comment: I'm creating a recordset which I need to be able to edit so no passthrough sadly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior. You should apply some aggregate function : Sum, Count, First, Last to each attribute, you didn't apply group.

```
SELECT `a`, First(`b`), First(`c`) FROM `tblMyTable` GROUP BY `a`;
```